# How to Find Out Who Deleted or Dropped Database in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Database "disappeared" from the SQL Server 2012. I have tried two solutions below without any luck. Please advise.

I've tried the solution from the link below but it did not work ([Database Missing ! Finding the root cause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666090/database-missing-finding-the-root-cause)) :

```
SELECT * 
FROM fn_trace_gettable
('C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG\log_19.trc', default)
```

I have also tried another solution from http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic989304-391-1.aspx

```
With cteObjectTypes AS
    (
    SELECT
        TSV.trace_event_id,
        TSV.subclass_name,
        TSV.subclass_value
    FROM
        sys.trace_subclass_values AS TSV JOIN
        sys.trace_columns AS TC ON
            TSV.trace_column_id = TC.trace_column_id 
    WHERE
        TC.[name] = 'ObjectType'
    ),
    cteEventSubClasses AS
    (
    SELECT
        TSV.trace_event_id,
        TSV.subclass_name,
        TSV.subclass_value
    FROM
        sys.trace_subclass_values AS TSV JOIN
        sys.trace_columns AS TC ON
            TSV.trace_column_id = TC.trace_column_id 
    WHERE
        TC.[name] = 'EventSubClass'
    )
SELECT
    TE.[name],
    I.ApplicationName,
    I.BigintData1,
    I.ClientProcessID,
    I.ColumnPermissions,
    I.DatabaseID,
    I.DatabaseName,
    I.DBUserName,
    I.Duration,
    I.EndTime,
    I.Error,
    I.EventSequence,
    Convert(nvarchar(10), I.EventSubClass) + N'-' + ESC.subclass_name as EventSubClass,
    I.FileName,
    I.HostName,
    I.IndexID,
    I.IntegerData,
    I.IsSystem,
    I.LineNumber,
    I.LoginName,
    I.LoginSid,
    I.NestLevel,
    I.NTDomainName,
    I.NTUserName,
    I.ObjectID,
    I.ObjectID2,
    I.ObjectName,
    Convert(nvarchar(10), I.ObjectType) + N'-' + OT.subclass_name as ObjectType,
    I.OwnerName,
    I.ParentName,
    I.Permissions,
    I.RequestID,
    I.RoleName,
    I.ServerName,
    I.SessionLoginName,
    I.Severity,
    I.SPID,
    I.StartTime,
    I.State,
    I.Success,
    I.TargetLoginName,
    I.TargetLoginSid,
    I.TargetUserName,
    I.TextData,
    I.TransactionID,
    I.Type,
    I.XactSequence
FROM
    sys.traces T CROSS Apply 
    sys.fn_trace_gettable(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('_', T.[path]) <> 0
                              THEN SUBSTRING(T.PATH, 1, CHARINDEX('_', T.[path]) - 1) + '.trc'
                              ELSE T.[path]
                         End, T.max_files) I JOIN
    sys.trace_events AS TE ON 
        I.EventClass = TE.trace_event_id LEFT JOIN
    cteEventSubClasses AS ESC ON
        TE.trace_event_id = ESC.trace_event_id And
        I.EventSubClass = ESC.subclass_value LEFT JOIN
    cteObjectTypes AS OT ON 
        TE.trace_event_id = OT.trace_event_id AND
        I.ObjectType = OT.subclass_value
WHERE
    T.is_default = 1 AND
    TE.NAME = 'Object:Deleted'
```

Comment: Why was the down vote required?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14187/1186

Comment: As for the down-vote, who knows? Do you think they stuck around to answer your question? Or would answer it even if they did? [Please see this meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes). Could be because you seemed to just slap two queries you found online into your system, then vaguely stated they "didn't work." What does that mean? Error message? Wrong results? No results? What is `log_19.trc`? Does that file even exist on your system? These are just guesses revolving around unclear / lack of research.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I get no results on all three queries.

Comment: Then it was probably dropped too long ago to still be in the default trace, so you are out of luck.

Comment: @Aaron - you own this place - the link to your own answer on stackexchange dba - very impressive.

Comment: Anyway, some other possibilities you could consider: perhaps the database was detached (this does not register in the default trace that I can tell)  - did you search the file system for .mdf/.ldf files that aren't currently attached to any instance? Also, it could have been renamed before it was dropped, so maybe cast a wider net in the default trace...

Answer (score 1):

If you use SQL Server Managnment Studio,
You can simply see all the data in the Report -> Standard Reports -> Schema Changes History

Details at: [SQL Server: How to Find which user deleted the database in SQL Server](https://www.mytechmantra.com/LearnSQLServer/SQL-Server-Find-which-user-deleted-the-database-in-SQL-Server/)